# Devel admin interface unreachable; or I broke my Devel?

Tags: 7, debugging, http-request

Not sure what broke where, been using devel & love it. I enabled the `Display $page array` option, went, did stuff, came back to disable and when trying to load `admin/config/development/devel` either through button, url or asking nicely, I get a

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection
>   without sending any data.

I uninstalled, reinstalled, no change. I uninstalled, deleted variables (shouldn't devel do this?) flushed caches, ran cron, deleted the devel folder, and reinstalled from a fresh download (7.x-1.2), no change. The strange part is devel still works (when module is installed), i'm still getting my $page array in the message area, but I can't admin devel anymore :'(

Unfortunately I'm ramping this site up for production & can't turn back now, might have to proceed w/o it.

Anybody know how to admin devel another way? Run into this before? Have something else I can try?

Update:
Just started testing the rest of devel & these functions elicit the same response (324):

- Execute PHP
- Devel settings (either the development menu link `/devel/settings` or the link in the admin toolbar `admin/config/development/devel`)
- Menu item

**Rebuild menus !** Thankfully this still works, because it fixed the problem! So try that if you start getting 324's in weird places!

Comment: Try clearing the cache.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, I did this and run cron after my second uninstall, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rebuild menus ! This fixed the problem!**

One of the menu tables must have been corrupted somewhere in my Drupal shenanigans.

So try that if you start getting 324's (or other non 200 responses) in weird places!